# Firefox & Ruby On Rails - hbs and js errors only in Firefox and only after deploy

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox, assets, pipeline

The problem:

1. I have a RoR project working fine in different browsers, Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera, and in the three standard enviroments, local, staging and production.
2. I'm facing errors only in Firefox, and only after deploy to staging or production. So, it's working fine even in Firefox local enviroment. Basically the visible error is malfunction of some critical web javascript related features.
3. Firefox console in staging or production returns first, html syntax errors in application-xxxxxxxxx.hbs (bad formed) and second, javascript errors in application-yyyyyyyyyyy.js (this._input is undefined)
4. It seems that js errors comes from the errors in the hbs file, so I've tried to solve html sintax errors directly to the compiled file application-xxxxxx.hbs in staging, but when fix one error, shows another one:

   - auto-generated comments
   - nested pairs of double quotes
   - input, img and other html start tags without the correspondent end tags (it seems the short way o open/close a tag suddenly don't work ?!!?!?!....)
   - etc.
5. All this error stuff has no sense to me since it works fine in all browsers, even in Firefox local... so...

What strange thing makes Firefox to be so special after deploy, when any other browsers works fine in any enviroment, and even Firefox works fine in local enviroment?

By the way, I suspect, that the problem could start with a Firefox browser update...but...really don't know.

¿Any ideas?

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: what on earth is a `.hbs` file?

Comment: .hbs is extension for html templates related to handlebars tool https://github.com/donpark/hbs